CSS not loading in Next,js app after Vercel deployment
I I need to deploy my Next.js app. I have tried both GitHub Pages and Vercel, but in both cases the styles just won't load. I've tried using SCSS and Styled Components, neither worked. What may cause the problem? This is the project's structure:

I have tried cleaning browser's cache, but it does not seem to work.
Here is my .gitignore file:
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.*
.yarn/*
!.yarn/patches
!.yarn/plugins
!.yarn/releases
!.yarn/versions

# testing
/coverage

# next.js
/.next/
/out/

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
*.pem

# debug
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
.pnpm-debug.log*

# env files (can opt-in for committing if needed)
.env*

# vercel
.vercel

# typescript
*.tsbuildinfo
next-env.d.ts


Can you show the expanded directory structure with the CSS files? Can you also show your .gitignore file contents?

The CSS files always needs to be imported into the TSX files. If you have global styles, import them into your _app component or root layout (depending on your Next.js version).

@JFK I have edited the question, have a look :)

@Schnitzler I have imported the scss files in the layout.tsx, does not work on deployment (even though works perfectly fine on localhost)

@kirvel could you also show the part of the code where you import the css file? a link to your app (if is not private) to see the problem would be useful too

@kirvel check the logs in Vercel. Simply navigate into your project > logs tab.
